# Bootstrap 3 : Panel collapsed by default

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my HTML

```
  <div class="panel panel-default" id="chartsPanel">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel-charts" id="charts-title">
                    <h4>
                        Select Charts</h4>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" id="panel-charts">
                <div class="nav" id="chkListCharts" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="280">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="distance">
                            Distance Comparison Chart
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="overspeed">
                            Overspeed Chart
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="idle">
                            Idle/Dormant Chart
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="workingnonworking">
                            Working/Non-Working
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="workinghour">
                            Working Hours Chart
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="fuel">
                            Fuel Report
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="temperature">
                            Temperature Report
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="rfid">
                            RFID Report
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="camera">
                            Camera Report
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel-vehicles" id="vehicle-title">
                    <h4>
                        Select Vehicles</h4>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" id="panel-vehicles">
                <div class="nav" id="chkListVehicles" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="280">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            PB 35A 3467
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            PB 35A 3467
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            PB 35A 3467
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            PB 35A 3467
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            PB 35A 3467
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            PB 35A 3467
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            PB 35A 3467
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            PB 35A 3467
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            PB 35A 3467
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            PB 35A 3467
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            PB 35A 3467
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            PB 35A 3467
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to set the "Select Charts" panel to be collapsed by default and the other one to be open.
I am trying to find the ways on internet as well as on bootstrap site but not able to do it..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#chartsPanel').collapse('hide');
});
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS:

```
#panel-charts
{
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#charts-title').click(function () {
       $('#panel-charts').toggle();
    });            
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just hide it with CSS and invoke show() on some event, i.e. when you would like it to appear.

Here's a basic example:

**CSS:**

```
#chartsPanel {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( ".panel-heading" ).click(function() {
         $( "#chartsPanel" ).show();   
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JVq8j/1/)**

Comment: Is there any bootstrap way to do it..?

Comment: and I want to open it by clicking on panel-title.. not by using external control..

Comment: Um.... you can tailor it to your application. OK, what id/class does the panel-title have? I can't see it in your code.

Comment: class is "panel-heading" and "panel-charts" is the id of the div to be collapsed

Comment: Ok, so i changed the selector to ".panel-heading". You have to put together a full jsFiddle if you want me to do it for you. Otherwise, tailor the code to your application.